# Website consuming more memory

Tags: nodes, blocks, panels, views

I have nearly 150 Panel pages and different template files. I generated lot of blocks using [Node Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module to be used in the Panel pages.

I guess this is causing memory issues in both MySQL and Apache configuration. Any solution for this memory issues?

My global memory_limit is 128M. Only after setting 512M in **settings.php**, my custom Drupal View is generating the output (otherwise, it generated a 502 error).

Is there a way so that I can set memory_limit only for my custom View?

Comment: As I already mentioned your Hosting server does not allow you to change memory limit, you have to contact them for that

Comment: Is this about Drupal 5, or any release above that?

Comment: It is Drupal 7.

Comment: @Nagarjuna: Its not about memory limit. I can see the reflection clearly. I increased the memory limit to 512M , only then the View started rendering the output. I updated in the description as well. Please see it.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Changing PHP memory limits](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance/increase-php-memory-limit) document, you can use

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

which should be in your `settings.php` file.

Comment: No, I have memory_limit set to 128M. But, this is not working for the View. I need atleast 512M for that view to generate all the records.

Comment: Is this in production? because some hosting servers will not allow you to change memory limit, even you set manually

Comment: Yes, its in Production environment.

Comment: Make sure that your memory limit works, as i already told you that some hosting servers will not allow you to change memory limit